# Display GL.POINTS and GL.LINES using SAME Vertex array-Android OpenGL ES1.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I have a vertex array consisting of 3d points(x,y,z values for each point). I am able to display the Vertex array as GL.Points and GL.Lines. Is it possible to display as GL.Points for half of the points and GL.LINES for the rest of the points using the SAME VERTEX ARRAY ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should be able to. I'm not sure which version of OpenGL ES you are using, but you could get creative in how you setup your calls to glDrawArrays and glVertexAttribPointer. For example, if you wanted to draw the first half of your vertex array as points and the second half as lines, then call glDrawArrays twice as.

```
glDrawArrays(mode, first, count)

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexarray.length / 2);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,vertexarray.length / 2, vertexarray.length/2);
```

This is saying draw the elements from 0 to vertexarray.length / 2 as GL_POINTS, and draw the elements from vertexarray.length / 2 to vertexarray.length as GL_LINES. This should technique should be available for GL ES 1.0 and GL ES 2.0.

If you are using GL ES 2.0, then you could loosely pack the vertex data into your vertex array and utilize the stride and pointer parameters to glVertexAttribPointer. Lets say your first vertex and every other vertex should be drawn as Points, and the other ones should be drawn as Lines.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(index, size, type, normalized, stride, pointer)

glVertexAttribPointer(handle, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (4*6), vertexarray.position(0));
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexarray.length / 2)

glVertexAttribPointer(handle, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (4*6), vertexarray.position(1));
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vertexarray.length / 2)
```

The stride of (4*6) specifies how many bytes you need to skip in order to reach the beginning of the next attribute. Here we have 4 bytes per float and 6 floats we need to skip in order to find the beginning of the next attribute. Essentially, you are telling GL here that you need to read past the current x0,y0,z0 and the next x1,y1,z1 in order to arrive at the next vertex we care about x2,y2,z2. In this example, this would draw x0,y0,z0 and x2,y2,z2 as Points, and x1,y1,z1 as Lines.